# What does one do regarding applets now that Chrome doesn't support Java?

Tags: java, applet

Without thinking, I created an entire program in Java and began designing a website to use this applet. All it does is create image in a certain way but there is a bit more code (classifications and default values/images) that I just felt was easiest to do with Java. Now I have a Java app and HTML CSS and JavaScript that I can't seem to do much with.

I have thought of 2 ideas (below) but I don't know what the general alternative is to applets nowadays.

I have a spare PC I may use and just alter my applet to run the back-end of a server-based site instead, but I am hesitant to use my own IP and bandwidth for something like this. Also, this app doesn't even need access to the internet so this just seems like way overkill.

I could just release the .jar, but I plan on expanding the available options. I also told people that this website was coming. I'd like to be able to just update the website.

I don't really plan on writing my program in another language. This took me time to make. If there is no way to work Java into my site, I may just abandon the project altogether.

I am mainly concerned with Chrome for this problem.

Edit: I would like to use GitHub as my host, just in case this helps at all.

Comment: [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/moving-to-a-plugin-free-web)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch That article is problematic at best.  Applets aren't the only thing deprecated starting in Java 9, Web Start is [also deprecated](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/9-deprecated-features-3745636.html).

Comment: @Powerlord I know. But Applets aren't "deprecated" in Java 9 (well, maybe they are, but it doesn't matter) they're already dead today.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch That article is still advocating moving from a dead technology to a technology that "will be removed in a future release."  I believe this removal has already been scheduled for Java 10 along with Applet.

Comment: @Powerlord [Java Web Start](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/deploy/migrating-java-applets-jnlp.htm#JSDPG-GUID-1F95EBB3-D5CB-434A-B069-2261900738F5) is still recommended in Java 9. *Migrating to Java Web Start provides the ability to launch the application independent of a web browser. When your user is offline or unable to access the browser, a desktop shortcut can launch the application, providing your user with the same experience as that of a native application.* It's only the plug-in that is deprecated.

Comment: @Powerlord Or maybe I don't understand what they mean by *Alternatives for applets and embedded JavaFX applications include Java Web Start and self-contained applications.* They do add *Java Web Start technology has built-in support for applets.* - I think that part **is** deprecated.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch You did read the link I linked way up in my first comment, right?  Here, I'll quote from it:  "**Java Deployment Technologies are deprecated and will be removed in a future release** 
Java Applet and WebStart functionality, including the Applet API, The Java plug-in, the Java Applet Viewer, JNLP and Java Web Start including the javaws tool are all deprecated in JDK 9 and will be removed in a future release."  Mind you, that link is the JDK9 release notes and `javaws` is the Web Start binary.

Answer (score 0):

You can run anything you want on the server, including java programs.  So
you could run the image creation program in the server and present the
resulting image using a standard img tag.

Comment: My only qualm with this is that it is a free service. I don't really want to pay for something few people will likely use. Unless there is a way to do this for free that I missed, I just cant justify spending money on a host.